# preg_match to find a word that ends in a certain character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to make a small program that searches within a timer (with this format 00d 00h 00m 00s) and returns the days into one variable, the hours into another, etc.

This is some of my code:

```
$time1 = "Left: 11d 21h 50m 06s <\/div>"

preg_match_all("/ .*d/i", $time1, $timematch); // Day
$time1day = $timematch[1]; // Saves to variable

preg_match_all("/ .*h/i", $time1, $timematch); // Hour
$time1hour = $timematch[1]; // Saves to variable

preg_match_all("/ .*m/i", $time1, $timematch); // Minute
$time1minute = $timematch[1]; // Saves to variable

preg_match_all("/ .*s/i", $time1, $timematch); // Second
$time1second = $timematch[1]; // Saves to variable
```

My regex isn't correct but I'm not sure what it should be. Any ideas?

By the way, I am using PHP4.

Comment: Show us some sample input please ?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you need? I've changed it so you can now see exactly what is inside $time1 variable just as an example. Not sure what else I can show that would be helpful? I just need the correct regex for extracting the days, hours, minutes and seconds. from $time1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will do the trick:

```
(\d+)d (\d+)h (\d+)m (\d+)s
```

Each value (day, hour, minute, second) will be captured in a group.

**About your regex:** I don't know what do you mean by "isn't correct", but I guess it's probably failing because your regex is greedy instead of lazy ([more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)). Try using lazy operators, or using more specific matches (`\d` instead of `.`, for example).

**EDIT:**

> I need them to be separate variables

After matching, they will be put in different locations in the resulting array. Just assign them to variables. Check out an example [here](http://ideone.com/hykbJs).

If you have trouble understanding the resulting array structure, you may want to use the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag when calling `preg_match_all` (more information [here](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php)).

Comment: Named groups are also cool `(?P<days>\d+)d\s*(?P<hours>\d+)h\s*(?P<minutes>\d+)m\s*(?P<seconds>\d+)s` :)

Comment: I need them to be separate variables, I tried splitting them up on my own but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Answered in the question :P

Comment: Okay but how do I assign the separate arrays to variables?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that's another question. In fact, if you don't know how to assign a variable, or how to access a value inside an array, you shouldn't be trying to do stuff with regex yet.

Comment: I know how to just not with the arrays?

Comment: Figured out how to use the regex separately, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always in the order you show, I wouldn't regex it. The following should get your job done:

```
$time1= "Left: 11d 21h 50m 06s <\/div>";     
$timeStringArray = explode(" ",$timeString);
$time1day = str_replace("d","",$timeStringArray[1]);
$time1hour = str_replace("h","",$timeStringArray[2]);
$time1minute = str_replace("m","",$timeStringArray[3]);
$time1second = str_replace("s","",$timeStringArray[4]);
```

Comment: It's not always in that order sorry. It can look like this: 8h 4m 5s for example.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is always this, two digits plus the time letter, you can do this:

```
$time1 = "Left: 11d 21h 50m 06s <\/div>";

preg_match_all("/(\d{2})[dhms]/", $time1, $match);

print_r($match);
```

UPDATE: this function can work with 1 or 2 digits, and match all the params.

```
$time1 = "Left: 11d 21h 50m 06s <\/div>";
$time2 = "Left: 21h 50m 5s";
$time3 = "Left: 9m 15s";

function parseTime($str) {
    $default = array('seconds', 'minutes', 'hours', 'days');

    preg_match_all("/(\d{1,2})[dhms]/", $str, $time);

    if (!isset($time[1]) || !is_array($time[1])) {
        return null;
    }

    $default = array_slice($default, 0, count($time[1]));

    return array_combine($default, array_reverse($time[1]));
}

print_r(parseTime($time1));
print_r(parseTime($time2));
print_r(parseTime($time3));
```

Comment: It's not always a double digit number i'm afraid. Any other ideas?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function: array_combine() on line 17:     return array_combine($default, array_reverse($time[1]));

Comment: Oh. array_combine seems to be a PHP5 only function. Are you using PHP 4? If so, you may try another approach, or use this snippet: http://snipplr.com/view/4918/. You can test the code I sent on this link: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: @RossJames OUCH. PHP 5 was released nine years ago, and PHP 4 was completely end-of-lifed five years ago.

Comment: Well, that snippet can do the work for you, but I strongly recommend a PHP version update, too :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't know how to implement that function into my program. Can you please help, I would really appreciate it?

Comment: Just paste the contents of http://snipplr.com/view/4918/ before the function I wrote.