# preg_match minutes and hours

Tags: php, preg-match

I try to get the minutes or hours used in a string.

**Example 1:**

```
$string = "I walked for 2hours";
// preg_match here
$output = "2 hours";
```

**Example 2:**

```
$string = "30min to mars";
// preg_match here
$output = "30 minutes";
```

Already read the question below. But doesn't solve my question:
[preg_match to find a word that ends in a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131029/php-preg-match-to-find-a-word-that-ends-in-a-certain-charcter)

Comment: I thought it is "*30 seconds to mars*". ;)

Comment: Will it always be in the format `xhours` and `xmin`?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky in this case: yes.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, **show us specifically what you did** so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "I walked for 30hours and 22min";

$pattern_hours = '/^.*?([0-9]+)hours.*$/';
echo preg_replace($pattern_hours, '${1} hours', $string),"\n";

$pattern_min = '/^.*?([0-9]+)min.*$/';
echo preg_replace($pattern_min, '${1} minutes', $string),"\n";
```

Please feel free to ask questions. Code was tested in PHP 5.3 output:

```
30 hours
22 minutes
```

Comment: I just want to note that having 2 `Xhours` in `$string` would only output the first.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `/([0-9]+)\s*(hours?|minutes?|seconds?|mins?|secs?)/i` by `$1 $2`:

```
<?php
    $string = "I walked for 2hours and 45    mins to get there";

    $string = preg_replace("/([0-9]+)\s*(hours?|minutes?|seconds?|mins?|secs?)/i", "$1 $2", $string);

    var_dump($string);
    //string(45) "I walked for 2 hours and 45 mins to get there"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/1Vjz4PNn)

This would work for

> Hour
>   Hours
>   Minutes
>   Minute
>   Mins
>   Min
>   Seconds
>   Second
>   Secs
>   Sec

of any capitalization (***but would NOT replace `mins` to `minutes` etc.***)

---

Alternately, if you really want to replace with different tokens (mins to minutes etc.), use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
<?php
    function replaceTimes($matches) {
        $times = array(
            "hour" => array("hour"),
            "minute" => array("min", "minute"),
            "second" => array("sec", "second")
        );

        $replacement = $matches[1] . " " . $matches[2];

        foreach ($times as $time => $tokens) {
            if (in_array($matches[2], $tokens)) {
                $replacement = $matches[1] . " " . $time . ($matches[1] != "1" ? "s" : "");
                break;
            }
        }

        return $replacement;
    }

    $string = "I walked for 2hours and 45    mins to get there as well as 1 secs to get up there";

    $string = preg_replace_callback("/([0-9]+)\s*(hour|minute|second|min|sec)s?/i", "replaceTimes", $string);

    var_dump($string);
?>
```

Which automatically fixes "s" at the end of tokens as well as everything else:

> string(84) "I walked for 2 hours and 45 minutes to get there as well as 1 second to get up there"

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/ms0FzXa4)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = "I walked for 2hours and 30min";
$pattern_hours = '/([0-9]{0,2})hours/';
$pattern_min = '/([0-9]{0,2})min/';
if(preg_match($pattern_hours, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3)) {
   // echo the match hours
} elseif(preg_match($pattern_min, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3)) {
   // echo the match minutes
}

?>
```

Comment: Should be `/[0-9]{0,2}hours/` without `^`

Comment: Furthermore, I think he wants to extract the number of hours (or minutes) : in this case he should use capturing parenthesis `([0-9]{0,2})hours`.

Comment: I'd use `+` instead of `{0,2}` for two reasons: you don't want to match "hours" with no number and he might be walking 222 hours.